# Is there a tool to read and write data using I2C?

Tags: i2c

I am testing out some I2C connected hardware and my C program is working fine using Wiring Pi.  However, what I wanted to do was read a byte or write a byte to the slave device from the shell.  I looked at Wiring Pi's `gpio` command but couldn't see any obvious flags to allow it to read and write from I2C.  Does anyone know of a shell command that I can use to read and write data through I2C that runs on Raspbian on the Pi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
```

Then use i2cset, i2cget, i2cdump.

```
man i2cset # for help
man i2cget # for help
man i2cdump # for help
```

Aternatively my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library supports I2C from the command line usings [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html), see the i2c* commands, e.g. [i2co](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#I2CO).